# Using after_commit only on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, observers

I have a UserObserver with `after_commit` (changed from `after_create` to avoid a race condition error that id not found) to update the count. But I know for every create, update is executing the `after_commit` code (which I knew would happen). How can I run the `after_commit` only on create? I have few solutions but a bit confused. I've tried:

1. Using `after_commit :do_something, :on => :create` in the model.
2. Checking the `created_at` and `updated_at` in the observer; if they're the same, then it's a new record.
3. Using `user.new_record?`

I am confused as I want to use 3rd one, but it's not working and I don't know why. I want to use observers only and not the model. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I am a little confused here. What do you mean by "It's not working". Can you clarify? In your observer, 
using: @user.do_something if @user.new_record? should work.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the original problem you're trying to solve? The only hint you give is "to update the count." Please show us the actual code you're using in your model and in your observer.

Comment: The 3rd one is not working because in `after_commit` it wouldn't be a `new_record` anymore.

Comment: thanks @diego.greyrobot..using just after_commit will run everytime..so i need to run it only on create in observer ONLY..its always running the code,which is not good performance wise..so how can it resrict it for ONLY create?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs using `on: :create` should work: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit

Comment: thanks @diego.greyrobot  I dont want to use it in Model..how can i use it in observer only

Answer (score 15):

From rails 5, Rails added three new aliases to handle this kind of situation:
`after_create_commit`, `after_update_commit`, `after_destroy_commit`

In your own particular case, you can use:

`after_create_commit :do_something`.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI the accepted answer does not work in many versions of rails and is a bug.  This ticket is referencing a different issue of multiple callbacks with the same name.  However, the bug is still there (any after_commit on:create doesn't work) in many rails versions.

'seako' has a workaround to fix this problem if you are running into it

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/988

```
after_commit ->(obj) { obj.do_something }, on: :create
```